# Java, Streams: how to convert expression with.collect(Collectors.toList())

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I convert

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> IntStream.range(0, i + 1).forEach(j -> list.add(Math.max(i, j))));
```

into a single line expression like

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 10) ... .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `flatMap`:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10)
         .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, i + 1).map(j -> Math.max(i, j)))
         .boxed()
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As a side note, you don't need `Math.max` here. In this case `i` is always not less than `j`, so the same result can be generated simpler:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10)
    .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, i + 1).map(j -> i))
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks. I only used Math.max because I needed any function with two int arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with `flatMap` :

```
List<Integer> list =
    IntStream.range(0,10)
             .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, i + 1)
                                    .map(j->Math.max(i,j)))
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT : just tested my code. It seems `mapToObj` doesn't work, so you have to use `map` and box the stream later.

Comment: It's actually possible to write `IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, i + 1).mapToObj(j -> i)).flatMap(Function.identity()).collect(Collectors.toList())`, but clearly `.boxed()` is better.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: if you are at finding funny ways to express the missing `IntStream.flatMapToObj(…)`, you can also use `IntStream.range(0,10) .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, i+1).map(j-> Math.max(i,j))) .flatMap(IntStream::boxed)`. But when both streams have the same primitive type, using `flatMap(…) .boxed()` is, of course, the best option.